# COSVisitorException Exception

Tags: apache, digital-signature, pdfbox

when I was testing my document, sometimes, I Inspect  that sometimes I have that following exception (not every time, sometimes, but I dont understand when it is happens, whay happens. I have onely that Error Log:

exception was at this line

**void org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.saveIncremental(FileInputStream input, OutputStream output)**

```
org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.COSVisitorException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.visitFromStream(COSWriter.java:1354)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.accept(COSStream.java:217)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSObject.accept(COSObject.java:206)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteObject(COSWriter.java:525)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteBody(COSWriter.java:435)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.visitFromDocument(COSWriter.java:1122)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument.accept(COSDocument.java:552)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.write(COSWriter.java:1501)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.saveIncremental(PDDocument.java:1369)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessBuffer.seek(RandomAccessBuffer.java:84)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessFileInputStream.read(RandomAccessFileInputStream.java:96)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.visitFromStream(COSWriter.java:1337)
    ... 12 more
```

when this exception was happening?

the source code:

```
  public void sign(File inputDocument, File outputDocument, DigitalSigningToken token,
                DigitalSignSettings settings) {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputDocument);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputDocument);

            int c;
            while ((c = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, c);
            }
            fis.close();
            fis = new FileInputStream(outputDocument);


            PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(inputDocument);

            create signature dictionary
            PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
            signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE); 
            signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ETSI_CADES_DETACHED);
            signature.setName(settings.getSignerName());
            signature.setLocation(settings.getSignerLocation());
            signature.setReason(settings.getSignatureReason());
            SignatureOptions options = new SignatureOptions();
            options.setPage(settings.getPage());
            options.setPreferedSignatureSize(settings.getPreferredSize());
            options.setVisualSignature(settings.getSignatureImage());


            // TokenSignature  implements org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.SignatureInterface
            doc.addSignature(signature, new TokenSignatureInterface(token, profile), options);

            doc.saveIncremental(fis, fos);
            }
```

exception at doc.saveIncremental (**not every time**)

before sign method, if I have **System.gc(),** everything works well. I don't understand why. before sign method I create visible signaure:

```
    DigitalSignSettings settings = new DigitalSignSettings();
    settings.setSignerName("");
    settings.setSignerLocation("");
    settings.setSignatureReason("");
    settings.setPreferredSize(0);
    settings.setPage(1);
    settings.setVisualSignEnabled(true);

    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("c:\\sig.jpg");
    PDFBuilder builder = new VisibleSignaturePDFBuilder();
// builder pattern, which creates pdf vith visible signature
    PDFCraator creator = new PDFCraator(builder);

    VisibleSignatureConfig properties = new VisibleSignatureConfig(originalDocument.getAbsolutePath(), fin, 1);
    ByteArrayInputStream template = creator.buildPDF(properties);


    System.gc(); 


    settings.setSignatureImage(template);
    PDFSigner signer = new PDFSigner();
    signer.signDocument(originalDocument, outputDocument, token,  settings);
```

I also found that, in Builder, if I comment one method, this exception is not happens. thats it/ PDJpeg caused this...

```
@Override
public void createSignatureImage(PDDocument template, InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    PDJpeg img = new PDJpeg(template, inputStream);
    pdfStructure.setJpedImage(img);
    logger.info("Visible Signature Image has been created");
    inputStream.close();

}
```

Or instead of   System.gc(), if I create for(int i=0; i<10000000; i++){} this works too! very, very, very confusing.  Oh.. I don't know  what hppens... thats very **confusing** for me...

Comment: Can you supply code and a sample PDF to reproduce the issue?

Comment: The main problem is that I can't reproduce the issue again and again. (for instance, if I run a program  on test, 10th test may be the good, and 11th bad (with the same pdf, with the same parameters).  I don't know when and where... project is too big, I don't know which part is bad written (to supply code)...  or where should I find the issue...

Comment: In that case... can you provide code with which you sometimes see the issue happening?

Comment: Yes, I've just updated it.

Comment: I found where it is happens. before sign method, if I have  System.gc(), everything works well. I don't understand why.

Comment: I just put your code (with a dummy `SignatureInterface` implementation) in a loop calling it 1000 times, and nothing bad happened. I'll make it run some more times. Just to be sure you might want to call `fos.flush` after the copying loop.

Comment: Oops... ok... I saw your comment too late. Well, a gc takes some time and maybe allows some IO to happen. Furthermore it may call finalizers... ah, I now got it, too, after 4800 attempts... BTW, I see many `org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument finalize WARNING: Warning: You did not close a PDF Document` log messages running by. Maybe that's related.

Comment: Yeas, I have did not close a PDF Document Warning.  but all the document is closed :-))) I should see again, if somweere is open my document. P.S can you tell me your mail? :)

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a bug in PDFBox. I ran into this issue as well and found some explanation on this forum post:

[IndexOutOfBoundsException when saving a document (at random)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1586)

I found this was the best description of the problem on the post:

> "The problem is that there is more than one reference to the scratchFile. The COSDocument assumes it has exclusivity over that scratchFile and will close it.
>   Sometimes a (single) scratchFile is being used by more than one object. As the COSDocument that created the scratchFile falls out of scope and gets GC'd the finalize() calls close() on the scratchFile - but there's potentially another reference to it. If the COSDocument kept it's scratchFile private (remove the getter) this can no longer happen and make the closure during finalize safe.
>   What we are seeing is that this stack trace is the result of the second reference to the scratchFile being invoked after the owning instance COSDocument has been GC'd. The getter within the COSDocument won't ever be called on the COSDocument instance that originally created it when the crash occurs because that COSDocument instance has been GC'd already - potentially long ago!"

The author has branched a [solution version](https://github.com/jmkgreen/pdfbox/tree/1.8.2.1), but cautions about memory leaks etc.

Hope this helps!